# Calling Powershell in a batch file issue

Tags: powershell

My powershell command is this:

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_printer | ft name, systemName, shareName >>    $PSScriptRoot\printers.txt
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize >> $PSScriptRoot\programs.txt
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_MappedLogicalDisk | select Name, ProviderName >> $PSScriptRoot\drives.txt
```

My batch is this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET Directory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%Directory%reimage_checklist.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PowerShellScriptPath%'";
```

If I run the PowerShell script in IDE, it puts out three text documents with the requested information. If I run the batch file, it outputs three batch files, but the network drive text file is blank.

Comment: Thanks Ken, i couldnt figure out how to edit it like that.

Comment: Remove the `-NoProfile` parameter and see if that doesn't solve your issue. Pretty sure that makes it run without loading the current user's info, including their mapped drives.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician That should just ignore the PowerShell profile should it not?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Removing NoProfile doesnt fix it. That was one of the first things I tried. Reading online, NoProfile says "Do not load the users Powershell environment parameters"

http://www.powertheshell.com/bp_noprofile/

Comment: Running the powershell by itself

[link](http://i.imgur.com/lgBtHaF.png)

Running the batch

[link](http://i.imgur.com/yhBrtMV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Bypass
```

To the powershell script and removing

```
-ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

From the batch file